# prevent pop-up from close after submit a form

Tags: javascript, wordpress

On the following website https://www.wetterschutzdach.de/ I use a pop-up and a contactform. When I open the pop-up and I fill the form and submit the form the pop-up is closing. But the pop-up should still be open so that the user can see if the form was successful delivered.

with the chrome console i see the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" class="wpcf7-pum" value="{"closepopup":false,"closedelay":0,"openpopup&quot;:fa
lse,&quot;openpopup_id&quot;:833}">
```

Is this code responsible for closing the pop-up after form submitting?

The popup is from https://wppopupmaker.com/

Comment: The code comes from https://wppopupmaker.com/ as  I just added to your question. You should have a look when you created it if there is a parameter you modify, such as the close delay: https://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/349-popup-settings-box-close-button-option-settings - change `"closedelay":2000,`

Comment: thanks for your answer... but when i raise the cloesdelay time the pop-up is still closing after submitting the form

Comment: I have no idea. Please look at the documentation